# What happens if you create a user with an ID that already exists?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Let's say I run this:

```
var user = new UserSchema { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I see that the `Id` property of `user` is generanted on `new`. What happens if for some extremely unlikely a user with the `Id` exists?

Comment: usually it's used UserName = model.Email

Comment: will throw a `DbUpdateException`

Comment: @tmg well.. it depends on how the storage is configured. If instead of EF something else is used (like AzureTables) you might not get an exception at all! Even with EF if there is no PK or other unique constraint on `User.Id`, you might success with an insert.

Comment: @trailmax As long as I live I learn

Answer (score 0):

If you have set UserOptions on Startup, for example *options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;* it will return an IdentityResult with errors (in the example here, the error would be *"DuplicateEmail"*.

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_CreateAsync__0_)